# How to change namespace for class used by imported class?

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

Let's say you have following class

```
namespace App\Utility;

use App\Routing\Router;

class Url {
  public static function get(array $params){
    return Router::url($params);
  }
}
```

You want to create class, which extends `App\Utility\Url` class but with  single difference. This class will have the same functionality except it will not use `App\Routing\Router` but `Admin\Routing\Router`

Something like

```
namespace Admin\Utility;

use App\Utility\Url as BaseUrl;

class Url extends BaseUrl{
  use Admin\Routing\Router; //but this is illegal use 
}
```

So the result could be

```
echo App\Utility\Url::get($params); //this uses App\Routing\Router
echo Admin\Utility\Url::get($params); //this uses Admin\Routing\Router
```

Comment: I'd like to point you towards this: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Comment: thanks but it's not relevant to this question. let's say there is non-static method which creates and returns new instance of Router class.

Answer (score 1):

`use` statements should go top:

```
namespace Admin\Utility;

use App\Utility\Url as BaseUrl;
use Admin\Routing\Router;

class Url extends BaseUrl{
   public static function get(array $params){
       return Router::url($params);
   }   
}
```

Note, `Url::get` must be overridden even tho it looks identical to `BaseUrl::get`.

Comment: Then I would be forced to override hundreds of methods. That's the point of question - I want to avoid it.

Comment: Unfortunately it is unavoidable with static routers.

Answer (score 1):

I see this as a classical case of Inheritance vs Composition... citing [Steven Lowe](https://www.thoughtworks.com/de/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose) :

> If you find that your subclass is removing things provided by the
>   superclass, question inheriting from that superclass.

That said, I would go with composition and implement the `get` function in the `Admin\Utility\Url` class to use the `Admin\Routing\Router` class.